# Regex end of match with multiple OR conditions

Tags: regex

I want to seach all matches for a product reference with RegEx. The product references allways stars with "XXV-" followed by a number and in some cases with one or two chars. Some examples: "XXV-1234-AB", "XXV-1232", "XXV-12-X". The only anchor for the match is the start.

In this sample:

```
<div>Reference to search is XXV-1234-BH</div>
<div>Other reference to search is XXV-1235-VC
</div>
<div>And XXV-1236-HG
also</div>
```

I need to math all tree codes, better with a single regular expression.

I try with:

1. **(?=XXV-).*?(?=<)** that only matches the first.
2. **(?=XXV-).*?(?=\n)** matches all, but with **< /div>** of the first

It's posible to match "<" or "\n"?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You know _exactly_ what the product reference looks like ("XXV-" then digits then maybe 1 or 2 characters), so why are you using `.*?` and delimiting it with an _unknown_ anchor like "(?=<)"? You don't know what comes after the product reference, so why design your regex in such a way? It would've been trivial to convert "XXV-", "some digits", "maybe 1/2 characters" into regex... And where are these "multiple OR conditions" you mentioned in the title? All I can see is _one_ "maybe" condition.

Comment: You're right Rawing, and the solution provided by Tom Lord Works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your question about 'matching "<" or "\n"'? You know exactly what the format should be, so just build a regex for it.

> The product references always stars with "XXV-" followed by a number and in some cases with one or two chars.

This can be matched by:

```
XXV-\d+(-[A-Z]{1,2})?
```

- `[A-Z]` means "any character between `A` and `Z`". If you want to include other characters, e.g. lower-case, you could use: `[a-zA-Z]`.
- `{1,2}` means 1-2 of the previous pattern (in this case, `[A-Z]`).
- `?` makes the capture group optional.
- `\d` means any digit, i.e. it is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

[Here is a demo, with some test cases](https://regex101.com/r/zUqiE7/1)